# I'm getting Runtime Error in a problem from Code Forces

Tags: c++

Here is the problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1256/problem/D .I'm getting runtime error("out of bound") in test case 15 here is my submission: https://codeforces.com/contest/1256/submission/84865113

Where am I doing wrong?
my approach:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
 
    int t;
    cin>>t;
 
    while (t--){
 
        int n,k;
        cin>>n>>k;
 
        string num;
        cin>>num;
 
        int start = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 
            if(num[i]=='0' && k>0){
 
                if((k-abs(i-start))>=0){
 
                    swap(num[start],num[i]);
                    k = k - abs(i-start);
                    start++;
                }
                else{
                    swap(num[i],num[i-k]);
                    k = 0;
                }
            }
        }
 
        cout<<num<<"\n";
 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As soon as you get `k == 0`, you should get out of the loop (`break;`)

Comment: not working :| @Damien

Comment: Please provide input, actual output and expected output

Comment: Could you please check this link? Code Forces does not provide all the Test cases though https://codeforces.com/contest/1256/submission/84865113 @Thomas Sablik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

the range of `k` is out of int. You should use `long long`.

Comment: Ooooh my mind!!! Sometimes it doesn;t work at all.... Thanks dude @guapi

Answer (score 0):

9428683473 is out of 2147483647(max value for type int), so you should not use int. And the var i and start should change too.